# Inflate() ignores XML params and setLayoutParams() break setOnClickListener(this)

Tags: android, android-view, android-inflate

Here is a custom view:

```
public class SelectFrame extends FrameLayout implements FrameLayout.OnClickListener{

    public SelectFrame(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.photo_selectable, this);

        this.setOnClickListener(this);

        setLayoutParams(
                new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT)
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.i("test", "yee!!");
    }

}
```

The problem: `R.layout.photo_selectable` has in its xml in the outer view:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

However these are getting ignored when I use `inflate(getContext(), R.layout.photo_selectable, this);`.

So that makes me set the parameters programmatically:

```
setLayoutParams(
        new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT)
);
```

I use `TableRow.LayoutParams` since TableRow would be the parent view. Now the layouts are correctly drawn but this leads to break the `this.setOnClickListener(this);` (the onclick() doesn't fire).

How can I have the custom `SelectFrame` view be filled in the parent but also have the OnClickListener work?

Answer (score 0):

You seem somewhat confused. The layout parameters specified in XML are applied to the views specified in XML. They don't apply to the SelectFrame that hosts the views specified in XML.

As for your `onClick` not being called, most likely one of your child views is handling the event before you see it.